# Android Nougat 7.0 trust all certificates https SSL

Tags: android, ssl, https, x509certificate, android-7.0-nougat

Hi my current app has trust all certificate policy and it was working fine up to Marshmellow since nougat it stopped working, I guess due to the changes in 7.0

However I was wondering if there is a way I can make trust all certificates work on nougat. Please help.

My current code to trust all certifcates..

```
public static void trustAllHosts() {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
    }};

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection
                .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**error log**

```
05-09 14:58:09.491 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
05-09 14:58:09.491 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:429)
05-09 14:58:09.491 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
05-09 14:58:09.492 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
05-09 14:58:09.492 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
05-09 14:58:09.492 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
05-09 14:58:09.492 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
05-09 14:58:09.492 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
05-09 14:58:09.492 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
05-09 14:58:09.497 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
05-09 14:58:09.497 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
05-09 14:58:09.497 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
05-09 14:58:09.498 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
05-09 14:58:09.498 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
05-09 14:58:09.498 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at uk.co.yotta.sharedLibrary.core.SharedRemoteDataRequests.requestServerStatus(SharedRemoteDataRequests.java:318)
05-09 14:58:09.498 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting.core.RemoteDataRequests.requestServerStatus(RemoteDataRequests.java:99)
05-09 14:58:09.498 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting.activities.ServerSettingsActivity.getServerStatus(ServerSettingsActivity.java:347)
05-09 14:58:09.498 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting.fragments.SetupServerFragment$ServerConnectionTask.doInBackground(SetupServerFragment.java:177)
05-09 14:58:09.507 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting.fragments.SetupServerFragment$ServerConnectionTask.doInBackground(SetupServerFragment.java:163)
05-09 14:58:09.508 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
05-09 14:58:09.508 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-09 14:58:09.509 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
05-09 14:58:09.510 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
05-09 14:58:09.510 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
05-09 14:58:09.510 12590-14060/uk.co.yotta.www.streetlighting W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: hi I have posted the wrong error log.. please find above the updated error log.. thanks..

Comment: "connection refused" may be caused by several reasons, i'm not sure if the trust manager is the problem

Comment: ok i think got some more info now.. it says handshake refused..  but when i try to connect to the same one on marshmellow it works..

Comment: is the server publicly accessible? do you have control over the server? android nougat disabled old cipher suites, which may explain the connection issues. If you can configure the server, make sure its TLS setup is up to date https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#tls-ssl

Comment: that helped apparently there seems to be a issue with TLS certificcate, once added support for TLS 1.2 and above it worked like a charm. Thanks